# How to effectively find the closest subset in a complete graph?

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, distance

I have some a set of **6** objects on the surface of a sphere.

So, pairs of objects have a defined distance, and the goal is to classify if each set of objects are "closely enough packed" or not.

My supervisor suggested:

```
closePackedSet = false
for each (x,y,z) in set:
   if maxDistance((x,y),(y,z),(z,x)) < threshold:
       closePackedSet = true
```

This is quite arbirary, and in fact not fast enough since time in this context is a big issue. So not calculating the distance between each pair on this sphere is also an issue.

What is a smarter way to approximate "proximity"?

Comment: The objects are particle physics **jets**.

Comment: I'd start with checking out algorithms to compute a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).

Comment: With just six objects, I'm surprised this isn't fast enough. Is this code being called in a very tight loop?